# How to display Math equations and Chemical formulas in Flex 4 text controls?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to display Math equations and Chemical formulas in a Spark (Adobe Flex 4) text control. What are my options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this product - fMath for Flex, claims to be capable of displaying math formulas coded in MathML in Flex

http://www.fmath.info/flex/download.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Math and Chemical symbols, but you can display special characters by using a character’s numeric value

```
i.e. &#169; for copyright symbol
```

See flexexamples for an example: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/02/using-special-characters-in-your-flex-applications/

Comment: thx wajiw but I' looking for means to display complex Math equations in Spark text controls.

Answer (score 0):

The usual practice is to embed a font that supports maths symbols in your application. Make sure the font you choose has all the symbols you need to use. [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) is one of the many freely available font families that support mathematical symbols. I am not sure if it supports chemical symbols as well. A guide to using embedded fonts is available [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html).